# Page reload causes redux state to turn DEFAULT (REACT/REDUX)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I'm working on a Project in React with Redux using Firebase RTD. 
After successful login, an action is dispatched which changes the redux state **"LOGGED_IN"** to `true`.

---

User is redirected to /Main Page, as shown below:

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.loggedIn === true) {
        this.props.history.push('/Main');
    }
}
```

After going to the `/Main` page, the redux state **"LOGGED_IN"** remains true (as expected) in the constructor, but when the page is reloaded/refreshed, the redux state **"LOGGED_IN"** turns default `(false)` in the constructor which causes my AUTHENTICATION logic become bad. Is there any way to persist the **"LOGGED_IN"** state to "true" in constructor till the user is logged in ?

Comment: Persistent data is not a part of redux functionalities. Consider using cookie or localStorage, or use supporting plugins like redux-persist to handle your data.

Comment: read this: https://redux.js.org/faq/miscellaneous#how-can-i-implement-authentication-in-redux